# AS3 - Decode JSON

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I'm new to JSON. [This](http://pastebin.com/Xay6cV3B) is the .json I want to decode but I always get this error:

> JSONParseError: Unexpected h encountered

This is my code:

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
    //
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    request.url = "twitter.json";
    //
    loader.load(request);
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, decodeJSON);
    //
    function decodeJSON(event:Event):void {
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target) 
    var jsonArray:Array = JSON.decode(loader.data);
    }
```

What's wrong with it?
Thanks.

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid.  Paste it into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).  The error will be highlighted for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. JSON is valid now but I receive this error from Flash: **TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed**. Why?

Comment: @Lee, that is a completely valid typecast the way it is.

Comment: @32bitkid - you're right.  I removed the comment because it was wrong.  I bet the issue is actually coming from line #12 - `JSON.decode(...)` returns `Object`, not `Array`.

Answer (score 2):

It's an array not an object, so do this:

```
//var jsonArray:Array = JSON.decode(loader.data);
var jsonObject:Object = JSON.decode(loader.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape your href double quotes with a backspace